# access value from table returned by survival analysis

Tags: stata

I have the following output of survival analysis in form of a table. This was the result of running the command `sts list`. I am interested in extracting the survivor function value at the end of the table i.e. 0.7854   and use it for further calculation. Is there a way to do that in Stata from such a table of results?

The code to generate the output is as follows:

```
webuse stan3
stset, noshow
sts list

    Beg.        Net Survivor    Std.
Time    Total   Fail    Lost    Function    Error   [95% Conf. Int.]

1   103 1   0   0.9903  0.0097  0.9331    0.9986
2   102 3   0   0.9612  0.0190  0.8998    0.9852
3   99  3   0   0.9320  0.0248  0.8627    0.9670
5   96  1   0   0.9223  0.0264  0.8507    0.9604
5.1 95  1   0   0.9126  0.0278  0.8388    0.9535
6   94  2   0   0.8932  0.0304  0.8155    0.9394
8   92  1   0   0.8835  0.0316  0.8040    0.9321
9   91  1   0   0.8738  0.0327  0.7926    0.9247
11  90  0   1   0.8738  0.0327  0.7926    0.9247
12  89  1   0   0.8640  0.0338  0.7811    0.9171
16  88  3   0   0.8345  0.0367  0.7474    0.8937
17  85  1   0   0.8247  0.0375  0.7363    0.8857
18  84  1   0   0.8149  0.0383  0.7253    0.8777
21  83  2   0   0.7952  0.0399  0.7034    0.8614
28  81  1   0   0.7854  0.0406  0.6926    0.8531
```

When I run

```
return list
```

I get:

```
scalars:
                  r(N) =  172
```

Comment: +1 for a reproducible example. But the image is not easily readable. Copy and paste of results is preferable to screenshot images.

Comment: Much better! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sts list, saving(OUTPUT)
use OUTPUT.dta,clear
collapse (last)survivor
```